# How does one actually set maxFilesPerTrigger in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to limit the number of files per trigger (`maxFilesPerTrigger`) to adjust micro-batching for my streaming workflow. I read the documentation but I can't exactly figure out if it's possible to set in spar.conf.set(...) or is it only set using .readStream?

Can I set it through `spark.conf.set` when setting up a spark session>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here you have all properties](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) you can set when creating the `SparkSession`. There is no such a property like `maxFilesPerTrigger`.

`maxFilesPerTrigger` is a [`DataStreamReader`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.html) option. No a Spark configuration property.

Comment: That's what I thought, I couldn't find it in the configuration thus it's not a property.